# Por que, a margem de cima e baixo alteram ao redimencionar a página?

Tags: html

Eu tenho o seguinte código utilizando uma margem de `5%` para cima e baixo nos elementos `.box`:

```css
.box {
  width: 150px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: red;
  border: 5px solid black;
  margin: 5% auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Ao redimensionar a largura da página para mais a margem começa subir de valor e se redimensionar para menos ela diminui o valor.

[Imagem da página sendo redimensionada](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsqT9.gif)

Por que, os valores se alteram da margem de cima e baixo, isso não era para acontecer caso eu redimensionasse a altura e não a largura da página? Nesse caso a margem é relativa a página?

Comment: É o normal isso que está acontecendo. A porcentagem é em relação a largura do bloco superior, conforme especificação do CSS, que no caso você especificou como auto. Variando a largura, varia o cálculo. https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/margin#valores

Comment: @Bacco A pergunta não seria dentro do escopo? Pelo seu comentário, me parece uma pergunta válida pro site, até por isso não ser algo intuitivo - apesar de estar na especificação.

Comment: @JéfBueno está na especificação e no SOpt já. Edit: agora atualizei com 2 links, depois acrescento mais se localizar.

Comment: @Bacon, o bloco superior seria o elemento anterior? Como, por exemplo, se o elemento `.box` do exemplo da pergunta estivesse dentro do `body` o elemento `body` seria o bloco superior? Como você disse "Variando a largura, varia o cálculo", então sempre que eu usar porcentagem na margem, mesmo que seja para a margem de cima e baixo ao redimensionar a página o cálculo vai afetar todas as direções da margem (cima, direita, baixo e esquerda)?

Comment: Seria o elemento de **bloco** anterior. Não necessariamente o parent, se você tiver 10 elementos aninhados, mas não forem de bloco, não contam. O primeiro que seja do tipo bloco é que vai interferir. por exemplo: <div><span><span><span><elementocommargin> - supondo que não alterou o display deles para block, por default vai contar o <div> (que é block naturalmente), os spans são desconsiderados. E é a largura que conta para calcular %, não a altura. Sobre o @, procure digitar corretamente (se sua intenção for obter resposta, claro, senão o sistema não notifica). Vi por mero acaso seu comment.

Comment: Lembrando ainda que vc tem outras unidades relativas, como vw vh, relacionadas à tela, tem o em e rem, relativos a fonte e fonte da raiz. Compensa uma olhada em alguma documentação para ver o que serve melhor para o seu caso.

Comment: @Bacco, desculpe, eu não percebi que referenciei errado o seu nome de usuário, mas eu achei um artigo bem interessante com mais detalhes sobre esse assunto: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Containing_block. No caso, teria como usar os valores em porcentagem, mas sem alterar a altura quando for  redimensionado a página?

Comment: Tem, é só por dentro de um bloco de tamanho definido. Mas não sei se você notou, tem 2 links no topo da pergunta para postagens sobre o assunto. Um dos problemas para poder dar mais detalhes é que quando fala que quer porcentagem não dá para sabermos ao certo que efeito você quer obter no fim (falta dizer o que pretendia de fato que acontecesse no final).

Comment: @Bacco, eu gostaria que quando redimensionasse a página os elementos continuassem com os `5%` de margem em cima e baixo em relação ao elemento pai e também continuasse centralizada na horizontal com o valor `auto`. Porém, como você disse "é só por dentro de um bloco de tamanho definido" nesse caso seria complicado criar layouts responsivos já que o valor vai estar absoluto e não relativo (proporcional a tela). Obs: não percebi os links vou dar uma lida ;)